# mod_rewrite | htaccess Querystring only on specified Pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

basically i want to rewrite some strange urls with query strings to a specified url without query strings (so the given query string dosent matter in the rewriting url)
so how can i define that the matched query string only is matched when the subfolders are "dir1/dir2/?QUERY_STRING"

i tried:

URL i WANT TO REWRITE: `http://www.domain.de/dir1/dir2/?id=xyz:test`

My First try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=xyz:test    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/rewrite.php? [R=301,L]
```

This is working but it dosent matter what subfolder is selected (so it work on `dir1/?id=xyz:test` too and it schould only work on `dir1/dir2/?id=xyz:test`)

I tried something with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?dir1\/dir2\$ rewrite.php
```

but it doesnt work. i think because of i have a folder and no file extension like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?dir1\/dir2\/\.php$ rewrite.php [QSA,L]
```

what i am doing wrong?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Desired output, do you need to do it only if subfolder are "dir1/dir2/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add another RewriteCond, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir1/dir2$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=xyz:test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/rewrite.php? [R=301,L]
```

note that the [NC] means "no case"

Comment: ah ok i didnt know about the combine method. i will try this in a hour and mark as correct if its working. thx for your quick reply!

Comment: @nitbix - No, it means `NoCase`. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc). They will "combine" by default unless you specify `[OR]`

Comment: That is working good and im able to apply some more query_string checks with [OR] for the same dirs. THX for this hint!!!